# Setting up ethernet mesh network between Linux boxes

Tags: networking, routing

've got some old industrial computer from my friend which all of them have 4 Ethernet ports. I want to hook all of them to host Tor relays and other service. But to save money on buying a new switch (and for fun) I want to connect them together using Ethernet and a mesh topology. Where one box is connected to my home switch and all traffic going in and out goes trough that box.

However I can't find any documentation and tutorial for this on Google. Not even on Arch Linux and Gentoo's Wiki.

How can I connect Linux boxes together with a mesh Ethernet? Or is this impossible?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "meshed ethernet". You can **bridge** ethernet ports in Linux, so it will act like a **switch** with an internal port. Then you can make all boxes become part of one LAN segment.

Comment: That would work. But I want to setup the network as a mesh in case any of the *switch* boxes goes down. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify: If you bridge all four ports on the "old industrial computers", the *computers* will act like a switch. Linux bridges implement a spanning tree protocol (STP). So say you have four of these old computer A, B, C, D and a main router R with four ports; then you can connect each to each other: computer A to each of B, C, D and R, and so on. If you have more of these computers, you'll need a hypercube or some other, more sparse topology.

The STP will disable links from these multiple connections so only a tree remains, and if, say, B fails, the STP should recompute a new tree.

But I'm not sure if many people use the STP implementation, so there may be surprises in getting it to work.

BTW, the basic unit of networking is a *LAN segment* or *broadcasting domain*. Originally, these included all computers with taps on a single thick yellow [coax cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE5), but has been replaced by all computers behind a switch in star topology. "Meshes" have no concpetual place in this.

The other "classic" option is to not bridge, still connect all four ports in some topology, make each single connection a LAN segment with it's own subnet range, and setup *routing* in each of the boxes. On the local level, this is usually done with static routes, which won't be failsafe and makes the additional connection useless.

There is the [Border Gateway Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol) (BGP) which is used by the big internet providers to manage interconnection of [autonomous systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_%28Internet%29) (AS), but I've no idea if this can be used on a local level with a mesh.

Other, more experimental approaches are to use protocols and demons that have been developped more recently for meshes, but usually for WLAN and not for LAN, like [BATMAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B.A.T.M.A.N.) (Layer 2) or [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_%28protocol%29) (Layer 3). This is will require a fair bit of reading and setup.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you used crossed cables, and config at leat one of the boxes as a router, then you would be able to connect them toogether.

Answer (score 0):

when you connect all of the devices together setup static ip's for each interface and setup ip routes that specify the main node as the gateway.

This is a example with Raspberry pie's and wifi but in theory it should also work with cables.
https://hackaday.com/2012/11/14/mesh-networking-with-multiple-raspberry-pi-boards/